# Android custom titlebar style/theme

Tags: android, styles, themes, titlebar

I created an activity with a custom titlebar and a button in it, which is extended by all other activites. It works well so far, but when I use an activity whith theme.dialog the titlebar is not shown correct. There is a padding to the left and right of the title and height is limited to 25, I guess.

So I tried the same to the `theme.dialog windowTitleSize` as I did to the theme. But it showed the same result as if I just change only the title of the normal theme - a padding to the left and right and the wrong height.

After a lot of googling I found at least one solution that works here on stackoverflow. Unfortunately it fixes the padding for the titlebar at runtime with `Class.forName()` and `getField().` I could change the height of the titlebar with `layoutParams` the same way, but would like to set it all up in `xml`.

I browsed themes.xml in the ..data/res/values but could not find where the limitation of the layout is set. Finally I tried to extend the normal theme and create a dialog myself. That brought me to `Widget.PreferenceFrameLayout` and the following errors in my xmls:
In styles.xml `"no resource found..." on all "...android:border..."`

```
<style name="MyPreference">
    <item name="android:borderTop">20dp</item>
    ...
</style>
```

And in themes.xml "no resource found...android:preferenceFrameLayoutStyle"

```
<style name="MyThemeDialog" parent="android:Theme">
    ...
    <item name="android:preferenceFrameLayoutStyle">@style/MyPreference</item>
    ...
</style>
```

How am I supposed to use the given themes and styles the right way to set up the titlebar in theme.dialog?

**-----edit-----**

I recognized, that the mentioned attributs are not available in the attrs.xml of api8, so sorry for the hasted asked question. Sometimes I just can't see the forest because of all the trees.

Thanks in advance for your help,

Christel